# Plot time series data in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot per 5 second data over a period of 3 hrs. 
I have timestamp data and pressure values as follows.
My intention is to collect the data every 5 seconds and plot it for every 3 hrs

I have the following data which I am trying to plot

```
    Timestamp          Outlet_Pressure
2016-09-12 04:48:45        0.91
2016-09-12 04:48:50        0.92
2016-09-12 04:48:55        0.91
2016-09-12 04:49:00        0.91
2016-09-12 04:49:05        0.92
2016-09-12 04:49:10        0.92
2016-09-12 04:49:15        0.91
  ....                      ....

(data for 3hrs)
```

To do this, I have tried the following

```
#Fetch the timestamp data 
plottime <- as.POSIXct(pumpdata_perday_df$TIME_STAMP, "%y-%m-d %H:%M:%S" )
pressure <- pumpdata_perday_df$OUTLET_PRESSURE

#Define Margins. 
par(mar=c(5, 8, 4, 4) + 0.1)

#Plot the time series.
xlim <- seq(min(plottime), max(plottime), by = "sec")
plot(plottime, pressure, axes=F, ylim=c(0,max(pressure)), xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "l", col = "black", main="", xlim = xlim)
points(plottime, pressure, pch=20, col= "black")
axis(2, ylim = c(0,max(pressure)), col= "black", lwd=2)
mtext(2, text= "Outlet Pressure", line = 2)
```

But on running this I am getting the following error

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I plot a graph which will have time stamp per 5 second on x axis and value on y axis

Comment: `xlim` has to be 'numeric vector of length 2' (see manual). So your xlim has to be `xlim <- c(min(plottime), max(plottime))`. But this values are automatically plotted, because they are the limits of your x-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved my issue